# React Material Table - How to hide add button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

In material table, there is an option to hide/disable action buttons conditionally. Is there a similar option to hide/disable Add button present at the top of the table.

Screenshot

[image: 1]

Comment: can you please share code here?

Comment: @Mr.Developer Please refer this [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-with-material-table-forked-q088to) . I want to keep the duplicate action button present in each row but want to hide/disable the add button present at the top of the material table which is getting added after defining "onRowAdd" function

Answer (score 0):

---REVISED ANSWER---

You will have to override the Toolbar component using the components prop for the table. Right below your EditField component, add another component as follows:

```
  Toolbar: props => {
    const newProps = { ...props, actions: [] };
    return <MTableToolbar {...newProps} />
  }
```

This will do the job.

---

You can remove the code inside the editable prop corresponding to onRowAdd i.e. lines 53 through 58 of the sandbox link you provided. That will automatically remove the add button completely. Do note that users won't be able to add a row anymore though.

Comment: I know that removing "onRowAdd" function will hide the button but then the "save" functionality on duplicating a row through action button also stops, and I start seeing this error "_this.props.editable.onRowAdd" is not a function.

Comment: I found out a way after looking into the docs. I added it above my original answer.